# SYBASE SQL clarification

Tags: sql, sybase

I have 42 million records in a table employee with 6 column named; empno, empname, empsal, empadd, data and arcid.

I would like to update the table employee with the query the code below executes until the loop ends. When I try to update first 100 rows it is taking more than 1 hr to complete the update of 100 records. An index is has been for the column that are in where condition.

Could anyone provide me solution if possible to make the code to execute query earliest. Thanks.

```
declare @rowCountValue int
declare @nbLines int

select @nbLines = 100000

SET ROWCOUNT 100000 
WHILE(1=1) 
BEGIN   
    UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET A_ID='112354'
    where A_ID is null and DATED is null

    select @rowCountValue = @@ROWCOUNT

    IF (@rowCountValue != @nbLines)
    begin 
        BREAK
    end 
END
SET ROWCOUNT 0 
go
```

Comment: Hi,
i have 42 million records in a table employe with 6 column naming
empno,empname,empsal,empadd,data,arcid
i would like to update the table employee with the query
the above code executes till the loop ends.
Bit when i try to update first 100 rows it is taking more than 1 hr to complete the update of 100 records.
index also created for the column which are in where condition.
could anyone provide me solution if possible to make the code to execute query earliest.
Thanks

Comment: please 'edit' your question and add the details you've mentioned in the comment; as for the slow query processing times ... we would need a lot more information, eg, table locking scheme, `create index` command, query plan of the update; of course, none of the columns in the UPDATE statement match with any of the columns you mentioned in your comment ... so there's going to be some confusion as to what you're doing vs what you want to do; have you reviewed [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Your "where" condition uses the columns A_ID and DATED. What is the proportion of data where this condition is met. It maybe the index is not particularly selective. Does the index have both columns, perhaps post the "create index" command used to create it.